# How can I arrange the code without having the same code twice?

Tags: css, optimization, less

I have this sample:

**CODE LESS:**

```
.product.attribute.installment,
.product-installment {
    &:not(.list) {
        padding: 2px 4px;
    }

    &.list {
        span {
            padding: 2px 4px;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have the same values ​​twice for two different selectors.

I want to compress this code so that it is as accurate as possible.

Can you tell me if you can adjust without repeating the same code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `&:not(.list) , &.list span{}`

Answer (score 4):

Just put a comma

```
.product.attribute.installment,
  .product-installment {
     &:not(.list), &.list span {
        padding: 2px 4px;
    }
}
```